# blueprintjs css classes are not getting applied in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using `blueprintjs` with `React` and importing the components they provide works fine. But when I try to use `className` styles, nothing happens.

For example, I have this `Header` component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Logo from '../../assets/Cisco_logo.svg'

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="pt-navbar">
            <div className="pt-navbar-group pt-align-left">
                <div className="pt-navbar-heading">Dashboard</div>
                <input className="pt-input" placeholder="Search" type="text"/>
            </div>
            <div className="pt-navbar-group pt-align-right">
                <Link className="pt-button pt-minimal pt-icon-music" to="/admin">Admin</Link>
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
}

export default Header;
```

In my `index.js`, I imported the `css` files correctly.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';
import '@blueprintjs/core/lib/css/blueprint.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
```

These are my imports. It's weird that the components like `Card` work fine, but using the className to apply styles just shows plain text without styles applied.

Any help?